# Getting error when open customer form from crm in Odoo10

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

i inherited crm view and added a button on that form. And applied function for open that customer form from crm form. But after clicking on that button i'm getting error "ValueError: Field 'padding' does not exist".

*I my sharing my python and xml code as well as screenshot of error:*

```
class CustomCRM(models.Model):
_inherit = 'crm.lead'

@api.multi
def open_customer_view(self):
    ir_model_data = self.env['ir.model.data']
    view_id = ir_model_data.get_object_reference('base', 'action_partner_form')[1]
    partner = self.env['res.partner'].browse(self.partner_id.id)
    print("PARTNERS", partner, view_id)
    if partner:
        res = {

            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'tree',
            'views': [(view_id, 'form')],
            'res_model': 'res.partner',
            'view_id': view_id,
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'res_id': partner.id,
            'target': 'fullscreen',
            # 'context': ctx,
        }
        return res

<record id="view_custom_crm_lead_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">CustomCrmLead</field>
    <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_form_view_oppor"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <data>
            <xpath expr="//header//button[@name='action_set_won']" position="after">
                <button name="open_customer_view" string="Customer Form" type="object"
                        class="btn-primary"/>
            </xpath>
        </data>
    </field>
</record>
```

[image]

Comment: Try to restart the Odoo server and watch the log for errors or warnings at startup to post it here

Comment: Restarted odoo server also upgraded default 'base' and custom module but still getting same error.

Comment: No info then to be able to help you

Comment: Hello All, Problem solved. i have done a silly mistake that called action instead of view. view_id = ir_model_data.get_object_reference('base', 'view_partner_form')

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I have done a silly mistake that called action instead of form view id. Then view id should be
**view_id = ir_model_data.get_object_reference('base', 'view_partner_form')[1]**
instead of *view_id = ir_model_data.get_object_reference('base', 'action_partner_form')[1]*